# Raw sockets in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming

I want to write a packet sniffer that sniffs all incoming TCP packets.In one of the examples that I was looking instead of using SOCK_RAW instead of SOCK_STREAM?

```
try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)
except socket.error as e:
    print('Socket creation failed. Error Code {} Message {}'.format(str(e[0]),str(e[1])))
    sys.exit()

#Include IP headers
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)
packet = s.recvfrom(65565)
```

1) In the above case can I use SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_RAW.
2) What does recvfrom(65565) mean ?
Does it mean recvfrom all TCP ports instead of a specific TCP port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use SOCK_STREAM instead of SOCK_RAW you won't be able to read the protocols headers, but only the data transmitted via TCP. In the other hand, SOCK_RAW will give you access to the full packet headers. In your case, as you want to build your own protocol analyzer (sniffer), SOCK_RAW should be your choice.
2. The method definition for [`recvfrom`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) is:

   > **socket.recvfrom(bufsize[, flags])**
   >
   > Receive data from the socket. The return value is a pair (string,
   >   address) where
   >   string is a string representing the data received and address is the address of the
   >   socket sending the data

This method simply receives maximum `bufsize` bytes from the socket.

Comment: recvfrom() will recieve data from all tcp ports? how does the socket abstraction tie in with the ports ?

Comment: You don't receive data *from* a port with raw sockets, since ports are a concept of TCP and UDP. The socket will receive all packets with the specified IPPROTO_* (in your case, IPPROTO_TCP).